# What does Special Comment refer to in reference to a colorscheme?

Tags: colorscheme, comments

I've recently delved into taking an existing colorscheme and customizing it to my liking. While doing this however, I found there was a highlight option for special comments and I'm not sure exactly what that refers to.

Here's the exact line if it helps:

```
hi SpecialComment ctermfg=66 gui=bold guifg=#5f8787
```

Comment: `:helpgrep SpecialComment`

Comment: @romainl `special things inside a comment` which is that result isn't really any more helpful.

Comment: Yes it is helpful: it tells you that you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Dom ever used a `TODO` or `FIXME` in a comment?

Comment: @muru yep and there's group already for `TODO`, `FIXME`, and others under Todo in the highlight syntax.

Comment: It's Vim: customize to your taste! E.g. (for a C file): `syn match SpecialComment '///.*\n'` :P

Comment: @Dom Ah. Yes. Ok, I went looking and it seems Josh is right. There was no usage of `SpecialComment` in syntastic, and of the stuff shipped by my distro (Ubuntu 14.04, `SpecialComment`s were used by only a few major syntax files - `vim`, Java (Javadoc comment headers), Haskell (pragmas), and some more.

Answer (score 3):

`SpecialComment` is not one of the default highlighting groups (see `:help highlighting-groups`). It is a *suggested* group name for "special things inside a comment" (see `:help group-name`) (a minor group).

What constitutes "special" is left open to interpretation; scanning the default runtime files, it's generally used to identify things like Doxygen tags inside comments, header or similar notational structure items inside comments, and so on. The specific meaning varies for the individual syntax file, basically.